# Python Selenium, Scraping dynamic drop down

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium and python for web scraping and the page that i am using for testing this [link](http://www.blooddonors.in/)

But the problem is i am not able to handle the dynamic content of the drop down, here is the problem arises

While selecting the state, the city is loaded based on the state, Some Php and js are going in the back end as far as i know.

So, i searched the web and came with a solution to wait for the sometime please use this [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as reference.

The following is a part of my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_path = r"E:\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("http://www.blooddonors.in")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/select'))

select.select_by_visible_text('Tamil Nadu')
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
drop = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div_city"]/select'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Coimbotore')
```

I am using a windows sys and i tried using CMD. It doesn't need a wait function it works fine without it.

The error that i am facing is:

```
raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with visible text: %s" % text)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: Coimbotore
```

But their it is actually their.

If someone can help me resolve the issue it would be great and i can move on to the next.

Thanks

Comment: Have you printed `select` as a basic check that it does contain the desired text?

Comment: I cant print select, it raises the error and the execution stops, the above commands are working in cmd,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select **`Tamilnadu`** and then select **`Coimbotore`** you can use the following code block :

```
driver.get("http://www.blooddonors.in")
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('select'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Tamil Nadu')
drop = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('city'))
city_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='city']/option[text()='Coimbotore']"))
city_option.click()
```

Comment: Thank You @DebanjanB it perfectly picks the block.

Comment: Thank you the pleasure is mine.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium provides a select class which can be used to grab elements from drop-down menu.

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('city'))
select.select_by_value('430') #search by value, coimbotore is 430
```

Comment: Thank you,

But i am facing the same issue...

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"city"}

Answer (score 0):

Your second drop-down defined as `drop` while you're still trying to handle first drop-down (`select`) which doesn't have `"Coimbotore"` option...

Just replace

```
drop = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div_city"]/select'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Coimbotore')
```

with

```
drop = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@name="city" and count(option) > 1]'))
drop.select_by_visible_text('Coimbotore')
```

Comment: Thanks i made the changes and tried but still the same error arised, Thank you.
This is the error
    raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with visible text: %s" % text)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Could not locate element with visible text: Coimbotore

Comment: Yep. Your locator for `drop` should also be updated. Check updated answer

Comment: Thanks bro, i have checked your code still the error raises.

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@name="city" and count(option) > 1]"}

I dont know if i am doing things wrong,

Comment: Did you remove `driver.implicitly_wait(60)`? set it back :) Just decrease to 10 seconds...

Comment: Yes, i have removed that.

Comment: I have added that wait and it works dude. Thank you so much.